# create image file on server

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the facebook api to get the app user's profile pic and then save it on the server. I'm getting the image just fine, but creating a new image file and saving it in the correct folder seems to be a problem. I tried using the fopen and file_put_contents functions, but apparently they require that a file be created before hand. How can I save the fb user's image on the server? My code is as follows.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '12345',
'secret' => '12345',
'cookie' => true
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if($access_token != "") 
{
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user != 0)
{
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');   

        $fb_id = $user_profile['id'];
        $fb_first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
        $fb_last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];
        $fb_email = $user_profile['email'];

            $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large');
    $file = '/img/profile_pics/large/';
    rename($img, "".$file."".$img."");
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: "... they require that a file be created before hand." No they don't. There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: Um, I don't think that I'm leaving anything out. But, for some reason, neither of those two routes worked. I got error messages.

Comment: what's with the call to `rename()`?  can you revise your example to show us what it looked like when you tried `file_put_contents()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$img = file_get_contents(...)` img will contain the source of the image just save that to a file, `rename()` wont work.

Just do:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);//For debugging, in case something else

$img_data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large');

$save_path = '/img/profile_pics/large/';
if(!file_exists($save_path)){
    die('Folder path does not exist');
}else{
    file_put_contents($save_path.$fb_id.'.jpg',$img_data);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I thought that it worked. But, just got an error reading: Warning: file_put_contents(/img/profile_pics/large/100000034641562.jpg) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the directory where you're trying to create the images is writable, otherwise give it the proper chmod.

Like Lawrence said, the $img variable in your code doesn't actually contain the filename, but the image itself. For you to save it in a file, you would have to pass it to file_put_contents as a second argument, and the filename as the first :

```
file_put_contents('image.ext', $img);
```

Or in this case :

```
file_put_contents($file.'/image.ext', $img);
```

To save it in the same directory as the PHP script, you can use the `__DIR__` constant to get the absolute path :

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/image.ext', $img);
```